# How to trace reg model offset to address

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I add a reg (e.g. VRF050) in default map, and its addr should be 0x1000a050 as shown in
[sv code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJeTW.png).
But, somehow, it be transfered to 0x40028143 in simulation [SimVision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VaXJ.png)

Is there any way, idea or keyword I can trace for this unexpected change?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the base address of the default_map in the reg-model file. All the registers added to the default map are relative to this base address.

Check for the create_map() API in the file:
For eg:
`create_map('block-name', 'h400, 4, UVM_LITTLE_ENDIAN)`

In the above case, all the registers will be placed from the base-address 'h400 under the map.

Comment: Yes!! I did not change the "byte-width of the bus" in create_map(). In my case, it should be 4, but I used 1...
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to generate the RAL using synopsys' ralgen tool. You only need to write the RALF file in pre-defined format.